# He continued on his way. ('on' is a preposition here or an adverb?)

Tags: parts-of-speech

> He continued on his way.

Is 'on' a preposition here or an adverb?

Can I rewrite it as "He continued his way on"?

Comment: No you can't rewrite it that way, but I can't tell you why.

Answer (score 1):

A preposition describes the relationship between any two things, while an adverb describes or modifies an action. In this case it is an adverb, as the "on" goes with the verb "continued".

And no you cannot rephrase your sentence like that.